# CMS for a fairly large Mobile Website - Please Help Select

Tags: java, web-applications, mobile, content-management-system, saas

I am looking for :-

1. A mature, scalable and proven CMS solution
2. With Support for Mobilization (Android and iPhone)
3. Good Amount of Customization using Java / .NET
4. Lots of out of the box components to choose from.

Please help with recommendations.

p.s Are there any Mobile CMS providers which works in a SaaS model?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps [daisycms](http://www.daisycms.org/) however i think you would have to create your own css for mobile stuff

Answer (score 1):

You may try sitecore, it seems to have good support for mobile as well. Also, check out this comparison about CMSs and their actual support for mobile phones. http://www.jboye.com/blogpost/who-are-the-leading-mobile-cms-vendors/